# Does Vitamio support inline HLS video streaming?

Tags: android, video-streaming, vitamio

I'm interested in using [Vitamio](http://vitamio.org/) for an Android project that would use HLS video and support older 2.x versions of Android.

I'm trying to play the video inside and html5 `<video>` tag, but need it to play inline as opposed to fullscreen. Additionally, I want this to work for live streaming (i.e webcam) not pre-recorded videos.

Does anyone know if it can do this? Alternatively, is there another library I can use to make this work?

Additionally, if I can't do support back to 2.x but this can work in 3.x I'd love to know that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vitamio Network Protocols

The following streaming protocols are supported for audio and video playback:

MMS
RTSP (RTP, SDP), RTMP
HTTP progressive streaming
HLS - HTTP live streaming (M3U8)
And yes, Vitamio can handle on demand and live videos in all above protocols.